# Integration of three variable function

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, list-manipulation

I have problem to plot the integral given below for discreate value of tc like tc=(1,2,3,4..).I am try with code but it does not work.Pls. suggest.

```
     f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1 - Exp[-x*t/tc], {x, 0, 10}]
    Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[t], {tc,1,10,1}],{t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Can you rescale so that you don't have such large/tiny numbers?
You can split the integrand up into three regions based on which part of the `Max` is satisfied, using `PieceWiseExpand`, but for me Integrate on the result crashes my Kernel on v9 (currently using my v11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[f, fn]
```

The integral can be done analytically. Note that `f` is a function of two variables.

```
f[t_, tc_] = Integrate[1 - Exp[-x*t/tc], {x, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[t, tc], {tc, 1, 10, 1}], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

However, you could also use `NIntegrate`

```
fn[t_?NumericQ, tc_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1 - Exp[-x*t/tc], {x, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate@Table[fn[t, tc], {tc, 1, 10, 1}], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The plot is the same, although much slower.

Comment: Thanks @B. Hanlon